# Count number of subscribers of an ical file

Tags: count, icalendar, subscription

I'd like to know if there is any technical possibility in order to count the number of the subscribers of an dynamical generated ical file hostet on my server.

Example:
On a website, there is a link the user can click at which dynamically generates an ical file the user can subscribe to, let's assume with his mobile device.
I'd like to know how many users have actually this ical subscription actively in their device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most fool-proof way of doing this is to generate a unique link for every visitor, and then count the number of unique links in your server logs.

This is not 100% fool-proof as people might share their link, but it will get you quite far.

Comment: Wouldn't that "just" count the number of clicks?
If someone drops that subscription out of his device, I wouldn't be able to detect that, right?

Comment: Yes, because you need to keep in mind when the last time was someone hit your server. If it's over a few days you might be able to assume this person unsubscribed.